# Сервер не принимает значения с графика с фронта через js

Tags: javascript, java, сервер, null

Пытаюсь, чтобы при клике на график на сервер отправлялись данные, чтобы сервер производил валидацию полученных значений.
Js код распознавания области клика

```
    clickPointEvent = (event) => {
    let coordinates = getCoords(event);
    let promise = addClick([{name: 'x', value: coordinates.x}, {name: 'y', value: coordinates.y},{name: 'r', value: coordinates.r}]);
    promise.then(function (responseData) {
        let hitResult = responseData.jqXHR.pfArgs.hitResult;
        console.log("Request successful, returned hit result is", hitResult);
        if (hitResult !== undefined) {
            addPoint(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, coordinates.r, hitResult);
            drawPoint(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, coordinates.r, hitResult);
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Request failed", error);
    });
}

getCoords = (event) => {
    let coordinates = {};
    const rect = document.getElementById('plot').getBoundingClientRect();
    coordinates.x = convertToCoordinatesX(event.clientX - rect.left);
    coordinates.y = convertToCoordinatesY(event.clientY - rect.top);
    coordinates.r = document.getElementById("form:R_value").value;
    return coordinates;}
```

Инициализация действия addClick

```
     <!-- Метод js для вызова метода на бине (ex. rc([{name: 'x', value: x}, {name: 'y', value: y}]))-->
<h:form>
<o:commandScript id="addClick"
                 name="addClick"
                 update="msgs, hitTable"
                 action="#{hitProcessor.serviceClick}"/>
</h:form>
```

Обработка данных на сервере

```
public void serviceClick() {
log.info("Click detected!");
String xCoordinate = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("x");
String yCoordinate = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("y");
Hit newClick = new Hit();
newClick.setX(Double.valueOf(xCoordinate));
newClick.setY(Double.valueOf(yCoordinate));
newClick.setR(newHit.getR());
serviceManager.serviceWithoutValidation(newClick);
saveHit(newClick);
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("hitResult", newClick.getResult());}
```

Intellij idea выдает ошибку NullPointer в строках на сервере, где я пытаюсь из FacesContext вытащить данные x и  y.
Консоль разработчика выдает ошибку
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
после строчки promise.then(function (responseData) {
2 день безуспешный узнаваний, что к чему привел к провалу.

Comment: Я не смог в песочнице запустить код. Но судя по описанию, объект ещё не генерируется, но уже запрашивается. Ловите консолькой значение promise на разных этапах выполнения кода.
Посмотрите решение в этих ссылках:
https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=2186621&text=Uncaught+TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+properties+of+undefined+(reading+%27then%27)&lr=105100&redircnt=1644504678.1

Comment: Полазив в дебаггере понял, что объект promise не создается=> проблема на сервере, а конкретнее сервер не может получить данные из RequestMap

Comment: Вывел все что приходит на FacesContext  через  Map
10:38:31,460 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) {0=[object Object], 1=[object Object], 2=[object Object], ice.window=68kzgo5tv9, javax.faces.behavior.event=action, ice.view=vbgdzsq1:0, javax.faces.ViewState=-4867015024780862510:7279670872720486830, javax.faces.source=j_idt19:addClick, j_idt19=j_idt19, javax.faces.partial.ajax=true, javax.faces.partial.execute=j_idt19:addClick, javax.faces.ClientWindow=68kzgo5tv9}